# How to redirect to another page when two text inputs has filled without any button?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, validation

I want to create a simple static demo looks like uber and i couldn't find how to redirect to another page or take action at all when the two input element filled.

i will create two inputs field [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FDtG.jpg) and want to redirect to another page when two inputs given

Comment: It seems odd that you wouldn't want to use a button to confirm the action. What happens if the user finishes typing but realises they've made a mistake? Now it's too late to fix it as you've already redirected to the next page.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Add event listeners to the inputs - check their length and if their length is bigger than 0 you know that there is something in both inputs.

However, this will trigger as soon as you type anything. It's more likely that you want to wait for them to finish typing using a technique called `debouncing`. [This link has a good example of how to implement debouncing.](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/javascript-debounce-example/)

Comment: Thank you a lot i will try and let you know if it works as intended :)